# Advice for creating and scoring quizzes

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, powerpoint

I'm not sure where to actually post this (I'm pretty sure someone will chastize me tell me where after of course voting me down - expected).

I've been developing a bunch of files for Safety Training at my facility. The UI is built in Excel with Excel VBA at it's heart to get names and the Training program to run. The Excel file opens A PowerPoint presentation after getting your name and the program you desire and logs that data. When you are done with the presentation it opens as a Word doc - the quiz for that presentation.

My issue is this: currently all of our tests are created in Word (I barely know Word VBA) and would like to continue by just adding some text boxes and check boxes for the answers. I'd like to add some code to facilitate the automatic scoring of these tests by placing a button at the end that "locks" the test (so they can't change answers) then checks and returns the test score.

I don't see where Word Files can be locked as in Excel's "Protect Sheet". The scoring I am using seems to be flawed but that is an issue I can work out later if I stay with Word. I am wondering if it wouldn't be better and maybe easier to do this in Excel as it is set up more for evaluating data input.

Looking for any advice on what others might do if they had a choice to use Word or Excel for creating tests. I currently have no preference (except for the above - which I am not locked into) in which format to use, possibly even using a separate PowerPoint Presentation as the test itself.

Comment: I think your  question is fine up to the third paragraph, the fourth and fifth paragraphs have valid questions but because it's becoming more opinion based the community usually doesn't approve.  Personally I feel Excel seems like an easier choice.

Comment: I upvoted it since it is actually a fairly well-composed question. Furthermore -- the superiority of Excel for the quiz is objective rather than opinion based since Excel natively includes functions useful for scoring a quiz.

Comment: @John. Thanks for adding the Word-VBA and the upvote. I typed in Word and  that never showed up as a tag so wasn't sure it existed. I've done a lot of forms in Excel so I was kind of leading that way ever so slightly.

Comment: [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) - `Programmers Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for professional programmers interested in conceptual questions about software development` might be a good location for the question, though I will neither downvote nor VTC here.

Comment: @FreeMan.  I was thinking that  too but I am SOOOO far from a professional programmer. "Dabbler" is more like it.

Comment: Haven't posted there myself, but `professional` shouldn't matter that much. I dunno - maybe it's a real Ivory Tower crowd over there...

Comment: No, this is not an appropriate question for [programmers.se], and asking it there will generate quite a bit of anger. @Freeman: If you're not *certain* that the site fits elsewhere, don't recommend posting there.  The people at Programmers get extremely angry when SO users migrate off-topic questions there.

Comment: @KenWhite - cool. I did say _might_, though I didn't emphasize it...

Comment: This question is extremely borderline as off-topic because it's both asking for a software recommendation and it's extremely opinion-based (either of which makes it inappropriate here).

Comment: @Freeman: You should visit Programmers yourself and read the guidelines in the help center there. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite "If you have a question about... software architecture and design,  algorithm and data structure concepts" Seems to me to be a fit, but what do I know... ;) End of discussion before we get the "take it to chat" nasty-gram!  :)

Comment: @Freeman: This isn't *software architecture*. It's a software *recommendation* (Word or Excel) question. It's not even a close call.

Comment: If you decide that you want to use Word VBA, then there is a Protect Method for a Word Document Object. See the MSDN documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220366(v=office.11).aspx. If you use WdProtectionType of wdAllowOnlyReading, then users will not be able to make more edits to the document.

Comment: @Jane.  Thanks. That's the kind of input I really need. Didn't know that even existed.

Comment: Is Access an option? I've had reasonable success creating quizzes in Access. It's also easy to lock down so it's tamper-proof.

Comment: @ Mark Butler.  I am creating everything using Excel which at the moment is better for me since I don't know Access just yet. I actually have a pretty good solution using RadioButtons Grouped for each Question Block. When ready to score, a button press Protects the sheet & disables the RadioButtons preventing changes. It reads all the T/F values figures out the percentage score based on number of questions and correct answers. I just need to figure a way to evaluate a "written" answer for 1-4 "keywords". That being done, I'll be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

To try to answer the question: What you are doing seems like a lot of fun from a VBA perspective, and from a user interface perspective, but it seems to me your intuition is telling you to move the test to excel and I think that is the right thing to do. You have much more ability to lock down the test, could easily score multiple tests and create a multi-test curve, etc, etc.